# Rigorous meaning of the expression $\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^y |^0_x $

Tags: limits

I've seen this expression:

$\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^y |^0_x $

What's the correct meaning?

$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} e^x - \lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^x $, or $e^0 - \lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^x $, or what?

Comment: where have you seen this notation?

Comment: A WolframAlpha answer :-)

Comment: Would you happen to have a link?

Comment: It was shown in a step-by-step solution, which is accessible only to Pro users. Anyway, I'll write here the complete text

Comment: $\int^0_{-\infty} e^y dy = \lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^y |^0_x $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This resembles the solution of a definite improper integral. If so,

$$\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} e^y |^0_x = \lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}( e^0 -e^x) =   1 -\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty}e^x=1 - 0 = 1$$

Or in words, evaluate the integrated result at the given boundaries, then take the limit of the result.

Comment: That's it. Thanks.